# Declaring properties in parent class that are defined in child class in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

A simple example to illustrate my question:

```
class Animal {
  foo() {
    console.log(this.bar);
  }
}

class Dog extends Animal {
  bar: string;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.bar = "bar";
  }
  test() {
    this.foo();
  }
}

new Dog().test();
```

TypeScript error:

> Property 'bar' does not exist on type 'Animal'.ts

I understand the need to declare the `bar` property in the `Dog` class, but TypeScript also wants me to declare it in the `Animal` class too. Is this expected? Does one need to duplicate the property declaration from Child -> Parent classes when inheriting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does one need to duplicate the property declaration from Child -> Parent classes when inheriting?

No. Move `bar` to the `Animal` class.

Or use a typeguard:

```
 if(this instanceof Dog)
   console.log(this.bar);
```